# Как избежать ошибки при вводе данных? (Начальный уровень Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

При изучении Python я решаю задачи, где в условии заранее указано, что пользователь вводит либо число, либо строку. В обучающих задачах пока не объясняется что делать, чтобы избежать ошибки, если пользователь введет строку вместо требуемого числа. Например, нужно возвести число во вторую степень:

```
a = int(input())
print(a ** 2)
```

Пользователь вводит: `"ten"` вместо `"10"`. Появляется ошибка `"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ten'"`

Но что если я хочу написать программу, в которой на вход можно получить и строку, и число? То есть если пользователь ввел `"ten"` вместо `"10"`, то программа выведет не ошибку, а сообщение `"Введите цифру"`.

Или если немного изменить задание: пользователь вводит число, программа выводит это число в квадрате. Но если пользователь ввел строку вместо числа, то программа выведет эту строку, умноженную на 2 (`a * 2`, вместо `a ** 2`). То есть программа выведет не ошибку, а `"tenten"`. Это возможно?

Как это реализовать?

Comment: В прошлой ветке вы получили несколько ответов. Если какой-то решает задачу, пометьте его как решение галочкой.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Я новичок пока что :-)

Comment: Да всё хорошо, вопрос сформулирован нормально, свой код приведён.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ValueError` это тип объекта, который называется "исключение". Программа бросает исключения, когда что-нибудь идет не так. Чтобы реагировать на них в собственном коде, придумали try/except.

```
raw_input = input()
try:
    number = int(raw_input)  # Если ввели не число, выполнение прервется здесь ...
    print(number**2)
except ValueError:  # (реакцию настроили только на ошибки определенного типа)
    # ... и тогда прыгнет сюда
    print(raw_input * 2)
```

В интернете можно найти много полезной информации по запросу "исключения python".

Comment: Спасибо! Пойду читать про исключения.